# Не так, как(,) я считаю, (что)

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая?

1.1. Ваш Пётр ведёт себя не так, как(,) я считаю, надо себя вести.

1.2. Ваш Пётр ведёт себя не так, как(,) я считаю, что надо себя вести.

А здесь?

2.1. Всё оказалось не так, как(,) я думал, окажется.

2.2. Всё оказалось не так, как(,) я думал, что окажется.

Comment: Сэр, смотрите, я дополнил ответ спустя много времени.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сравниваем с [ответом](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/475433/%D0%9E%D0%BD-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82), которым я вам недавно дал.

В ваших примерах из вводного предложения не получится сделать грамматическую основу, образовав новое предложение. Поэтому вводные слова только обособляем:

*Ваш Пётр ведёт себя не так, как, я считаю, надо себя вести*;

*Всё оказалось не так, как, я думал, окажется*.

**Союз КАК обозначает структуру предложения, он соединяет части сложноподчинëнного предложения**.

То есть союз КАК — структурный, а со структурным союзом **нельзя** образовать спаянное сочетание. Структурный союз не может примыкать к вводному слову.

Примыкать к вводному слову может только тот союз, который нельзя от него «оторвать»:

*Мы знаем, **а стало быть**, верим, что сказкам сбываться дано* — перестановка союза **невозможна**.

И союз, стоящий в **начале предложения**, т. е. **присоединительный**:

*Но я в**и**жу, вам это не подходит*.

Если ударение падает только на вводное слово, то между присоединительным союзом и вводным словом запятая НЕ ставится, а если ударение падает и на вводное слово, и на союз — запятую между ними ставим (союз перестаëт к вводному примыкать; интонация — подтверждение):

*Н**о**, я в**и**жу, вам это не подходит*.

---

Почему случай, приведëнный Sharon, не подходит, я уже объяснил в ответе выше.

Comment: Максим, как много слов, разве все это можно прочитать?  А кто ясно мыслит, тот ясно излагает. Опять подстановки/перетановки вместо грамматического анализа. Разговорный синтаксис упрощает письменную и устную речь, а у вас там запятая на запятой.  А зачем?

Answer (score 2):

Я не согласен с Sharon. Я считаю, что запятые нужны:

***Ваш Пётр ведёт себя не так, как, я считаю, надо себя вести***;

***Всё оказалось не так, как, я думал, окажется***.

Объясняю своë мнение. Вводные конструкции и придаточные предлодения (про них дальше будет речь), как правило, можно опустить из предложения без нарушения структуры. Здесь как раз вводные предложения можно опустить без потери структуры:

***Ваш Пётр ведёт себя не так, как надо себя вести***;

***Всё оказалось не так, как окажется***.

Но что получается, если запятые не ставить, — вводное предложение соединилось с союзом — следовательно, они образовали придаточные части: ***как я считаю***, ***как я думал***, — а придаточные можно опустить **без потери структуры**.

Но если опустить придаточные, структура как раз таки нарушится:

***Ваш Пётр ведёт себя не так*** (как я считаю)***, надо себя вести***;

***Всё оказалось не так*** (как я думал)***, окажется***.

Так что запятые ставить **нужно**.

А варианты:

Ваш Пётр ведёт себя не так, как(,) я считаю, что надо себя вести;

Всё оказалось не так, как(,) я думал, что окажется —

являются некорректными.

Потому что — хоть ставь запятую, хоть нет — не получится сделать корректное:

***Всё оказалось не так, как*** (я думал)***, что окажется.***

***Ваш Пётр ведёт себя не так, как*** (я считаю)***, что надо себя вести.***

***Ваш Пётр ведёт себя не так*** (как я считаю)***, надо себя вести.***

***Всё оказалось не так*** (как я думал)***, окажется***.

Просто убирайте скобки — и получите ответ.

**ДОПОЛНЕНО.**

А теперь объясняю, почему случай из «Розенталя», приведëнный Sharon, не подходит. Дело в том, что [здесь, в 3-м пункте](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137#pp137), всë немного по-другому.

***Хозяйством нельзя сказать, чтобы он занимался.***

***Но эти слова мне неудобно, чтобы ты сказала.***

В этих случаях нет запятой, потому что, если опустить главную часть, получется некорректное по структуре предложение:

***Хозяйством, чтобы он занимался***;

***Слова эти, чтобы ты сказала***.

Плохо выглядит. И ещë одно отличие есть: здесь слово *хозяйством* взяли из **середины** придаточного предложения и поставили перед главной (*нельзя сказать*).

Теперь разберем ваши случаи и докажем, что это совершенно разные случаи:

***Ваш Петр ведет себя не так, как(,) я считаю, нужно себя вести***;

***Все оказалось не так, как(,) я думал, окажется***.

Пока не будем ставить / не ставить запятые. Давайте разберемся, в чëм же отличие двух случаев.

Если в том случае Розенталь не поставил запятую из-за того, что получится некорректное предложение, то здесь всë очень даже корректно и нет оснований запятые не ставить:

***Ваш Пëтр ведëт себя не так, как надо себя вести***;

***Всë оказалось не так, как окажется***.

Корректно же? Вот и я о том же.

И если в том случае из **середины** придаточной части взяли слово и поставили перед главной, то здесь ничего из середины придаточной не брали — просто между частями придаточного вставили главную часть.

А если еë просто вставили, то еë нужно обособить как вводное слово, потому что изымается без нарушения структуры. Хотя это и были вводные слова.

---

Вывод: запятые ставим в любом случае, это ваодные слова. А случай из 3-го пункта справочника не подходит. Нужно уметь видеть границы.

Comment: *Всë оказалось не так, как окажется* — чушь.

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр Поймите, главное — неразрушенная структура. Помните, я в вопросе одном (_Он, может быть, дома, но, может быть, нет_) объяснял? Смысл — второй план, структура — первый.

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр Вот просто подумайте над моими словами.

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр А если вы меня не понимаете так, то давайте не будем изымать, а переставим. _Всë оказалось не так, как окажется, я думал._ Даже так: _Всë оказалось не так, как ока-, я думал, -жется_. Важно, чтоб на месте, где стояло вводное слово, не было некорректности. Понимаете?

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр Изымаем мы слова ИСКЛЮЧИТЕЛЬНО ради проверки, но не более.

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр Ещë кое-что: https://foxford.ru/wiki/russkiy-yazyk/vvodnye-slova-i-konstruktsii Говорится о структуре, а она в ваших примерах не нарушается. Вы пишете, что _всë оказалось не так, как окажется_ — чушь. Вы говорите про смысл, а ставить запятую между вводным словом и союзом или нет — проверяют всегда по структуре. Структура НЕ РАВНО смысл. Вводные слова проверяют именно по ней, а она как раз таки не нарушается.

Comment: В ссылке смотрите примеры после слов _наоборот, напротив_.

Answer (score 1):

Запятой после ***КАК*** нет:

(1) *Ваш Пётр ведёт себя не так, **как я считаю**, надо себя вести.*

(2) *Всё оказалось не так, **как я думал,** окажется.*

Это **разговорная фразеология**. В составе придаточного (***ТАК... КАК***) входит сложная конструкция с двумя предикативными **основами**: (1)  я считаю, надо себя вести; (2) я думал, окажется.

Здесь тот же принцип, что указан у **[Розенталя, пункт 3](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137#pp137)**

3. Если главная часть сложноподчиненного предложения находится внутри придаточной (в разговорном стиле речи), то **запятая** обычно ставится только после главной части (а перед ней не ставится); ср.: Хозяйством нельзя сказать, чтобы он занимался… (Г.) — Нельзя сказать, чтобы он занимался хозяйством;

Comment: Sharon! What do you say?

Comment: Право же, я не знаю, сэр. Мне сложно разобраться в логике других участников, легче ответить самой. Но я надеюсь, сэр, что вы сами примете справедливое решение. Если вы не согласны с моим ответом, то отзовите приемку ответа. Согласитесь, что тема должна обсуждаться сразу, а не через 10 дней.

Comment: Я не изменю своего мнения. Разговорная конструкция построена по особым правилам. Это видно по интонации и по оформлению предложения с минимальным количеством знаков. Пунктуация должна разъяснять грамматику, а не осложнять ее.

Comment: А если делается мегапауза?

Comment: Где, сэр? Неужели поле союза КАК?

Comment: Да, мэм, после него-с.

Comment: Дело в том – я думаю, – кто *как* в обоих предложениях и к *я* относится, и к части после *я*, из-за чего толком-то не получается изъять это дело, и поэтому только одна – что вы сказали – запятая.

Comment: Дело в том, что не надо ничего "изымать", иначе у вас будет другое предложение. Мне не хотелось бы, сэр, чтобы вы пользовались таким методом анализа.  Это предложение состоит из таких частей, разделенных паузами, и никак иначе: Всё оказалось не так, // как я думал, / окажется.  Другое произношение некорректно и искусственно.  Вторая пауза произносительная (небольшая).

Answer (score 0):

**Второй ответ**

```
Дело в том, что не надо ничего "изымать", иначе у 
вас будет другое предложение. Мне не хотелось бы 
чтобы вы пользовались таким методом анализа. Это 
предложение состоит из таких частей, разделенных 
паузами, и никак иначе: Всё оказалось не так, // как 
я думал, / окажется. Другое произношение некорректно 
и искусственно. Вторая пауза произносительная 
(небольшая).
```

**Правильно**:

*Ваш Пётр ведёт себя не так, // как **я считаю**, / надо себя вести.*

*Всё оказалось не так, // как **я думал**, / окажется.*

**СХЕМА** **построения предложения** (в разговорной фразеологии):

(1) *Я считаю, надо вести себя **ТАК**.*

А Ваш Пётр ведёт себя **НЕ ТАК, КАК** *(я считаю, **надо себя вести**).*

(2) *Я думал, все окажется **ТАК**.*

Но всё оказалось **НЕ ТАК, КАК** (я думал, **окажется)**.

В данном случае более сложная конструкция (**СПП "я считаю, надо себя вести"** ) выступает в качестве  **структурного** элемента (**простого предложения**) при построении другой конструкции (СПП с придаточным **местоименно-определительным**).

Это явление можно назвать **КОНТАМИНАЦИЕЙ** (лат. contaminatio «смешение»), и оно не редкость в русской грамматике.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149854/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.