# Он, может быть, дома, но(,) может быть, нет

Tags: запятые

Нужна ли запятая?

`Он, может быть, дома, но(,) может быть, нет.`

`Я, может, приду, а также(,) может, и нет.`

Comment: Sir, you don't like my answer. I have completed the answer, look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Он, может быть, дома, но может быть, нет*;

*Я, может, приду, а также может, и нет* — вводные слова (а точнее, уже не вводные слова) выступают в роли члена предложения, а именно сказуемого, и образуют с союзом **одну из частей сложного предложения**.

---

Если это именно вводные слова, то запятая обязательна, — я вам про это уже говорил.

*Он, может быть, дома, но, может быть, нет*;

*Я, может, приду, а также, может, и нет*.

Почему? Потому что союз не примыкает к вводному слову, образуя спаянные сочетания, — союз ставится по структуре предложения, а вводное никак не может примыкать к **структурному** союзу.

В первом варианте союз разделяет однородные обстоятельства, во втором — однородные сказуемые.

Вводное слово может примыкать только к присоединительному союзу (и то не всегда — между присоединительным союзом и вводным словом ставится или не ставится запятая в зависимости от интонауии автора) и к союзу, не образующему структуру предложения и относящемуся именно к вводному слову, образуя с ним спаянные сочетания, напр.:

*Мы знаем, **а стало быть**, верим, что сказкам сбываться дано* — союз примыкает к вводному слову: спаянное сочетание; «оторвать» вводное слово от союза нельзя;

*Но я в**и**жу, вам это не подходит* — присоединительный союз примыкает к вводному слову, а интонация это подтверждает: показывает ударение на слове *вижу*;

*Н**о**, я в**и**жу, вам это не подходит* — присоединительный союз не примыкает к вводному слову; интонация: ударение ставится и на союзе, и на вводном слове; в этих случаях запятая ставится.

Запятую между присоединительным союзом рассматривает сам автор.

**Под присоединительным союзом подразумевается союз, стоящий в начале предложения.**

---

**[«Розенталь», пункты 5 — 6.](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122)**

Answer (score 0):

Правильно:

*Он, **может быть**, дома, но, **может быть**, нет.*

Проверка: *Он, **может быть**, дома, но, **может быть**, он не дома.*

*Я, **может**, приду, а также, **может**, и нет.*

Проверка: *Я, **может**, приду, а также, **может**, и не приду.*

Слово ***"нет"*** заменяет сказуемое/предиктивную основу в предыдущем предложении.