# Но также(,) возможно, и нет

Tags: запятые

Нужна запятая?

1. Я, может, помогу тебе, но(,) может, и нет.
2. Я, может, помогу тебе, но(,) может, нет.
3. Я, возможно, приду, а также(,) возможно, и  нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я вам недавно дал **[ответ](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/475433/%D0%9E%D0%BD-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82)**. Делаем по нему выводы:

*Я, может, помогу тебе, но может, и нет*;

*Я, может, помогу тебе, но может, нет*;

*Я, возможно, приду, а также возможно, и нет* — вводные слова перешли в сказуемые, образовав сложное предложение.

Стоит заметить, что в первом варианте никак нельзя поставить запятую, потому что будет некорректное по **структуре** предложение:

*Я, может, помогу тебе, но и нет* — два союза не сочетаются между собой.

Если вводное слово, то обособляем (союз обозначает структуру, поэтому никак не может примыкать к нему и образовывать с ним спаянные сочетания, а значит, вводное слово можно «оторвать» от союза — так, собственно, и есть) в любом случае:

*Я, может, помогу тебе, но, может, нет*;

*Я, возможно, приду, а также, возможно, и нет*.

Опять же, в первом примере невозможна запятая никак.

Answer (score 2):

1. *Я, может, помогу тебе, **но может, и нет**.*
2. *Я, может, помогу тебе, **но может, нет**.*
3. *Я, возможно, приду, **а также возможно, и нет**.*

**Примеры**

Р. С. Вереск. Большая Медведица (2015) // «Волга», 2016. — Мама, говорю, встретит тебя? — Может, встретит, **а может, нет.**

Вера Белоусова. Второй выстрел (2000). *Может, я и ошибся, **а может, и нет** — не знаю, не мне судить.*

Майя Кучерская. Тетя Мотя // «Знамя», 2012. ***Но может, и нет**, точно я ничего не знаю.*